# Why can I see my breath after I pop my ears?

Tags: water, pressure, air, evaporation, humidity

I have this weird but reproducible thing that I can see my breath for less than a second even in hot/humid weather. The key to do that is to **pop my ears** - I have to do that often, it's like I'm on a flight, not sure why my ear is that way... Anyway even if I just try to force more air into my mouth, keeping it flexed (not blowing it up like a balloon)... At the moment I open mouth and let the air out I can see it. I noticed it on a hot day in the car, against the darkness of the dashboard I could see the vapor. Also just about anywhere, anytime. It's barely visible though. My friend can see his breath during or after rain (!)... I think it has something to do with pressure and relative humidity - but then why does it work in very humid weather too, also in the bathroom? If I breath out normally it does **not** happen at all! I'd like to know the scientific explanation (and if it's normal or there is something wrong with me).

Comment: that is interesting semi related is I can repeatedly pop my right big toe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The relative humidity of air is pressure dependent.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_humidity#Pressure_Dependence)  Your method of [popping your ears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_clearing) involves increasing the pressure of the air in your mouth.  And if you sufficiently compress a volume of air that has a high relative humidity, you can increase the air's relative humidity beyond it's saturation limit, which causes the water [vapor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor) in the air to start to [condense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation), producing a visible [mist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mist).

You can find videos and descriptions of this phenomenon by googling "[mouth mist trick](https://www.google.com/search?q=mouth%20mist%20trick)".

Comment: And there's the related fact that when you lower the pressure you lower the temperature--and what happens when you lower the temperature of saturated air?  Condensation.